# statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Tags: vhdl, clock, sequential, synthesis

statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Try to reset =>0 signal u_txreq on u_txack edge and set =>1 it on CLK edge

```
process (CLK, u_reset_n, u_txack)
begin
  if (u_reset_n='0')then
    u_txreq<='0';
  elsif rising_edge(CLK) then 
    u_txreq<='1';
  elsif rising_edge(u_txack) then
    u_txreq<='0';   
  end if;
end process;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For HDL code top be synthesizeable there must exist some hardware in the target library which implements the requested function.

At the moment there exists no hardware that at the same time supports:
1/ Reset a-synchronously on an active low signal. (`if (u_reset_n='0')`)
2/ Triggers on a rising edge (`elsif rising_edge(CLK)`)
3/ Triggers on a **second independent** rising edge. (`elsif rising_edge(u_txack)`).

You have to re-write your code to use only ONE rising or falling clock edge.

Comment: Dear, could you look at the attached picture and advice how to make the code. In general need to back D signal to '1' within n-clocks after Q reset

Comment: 1/ If you have an a-synchronous input you must FIRST synchronize, then you can use the signal. I suggest you read up on synchronization. 2/ *"advice how to make the code"* would mean I would have to write the code for you which I don't do in answering questions. Also you specifications are not precise enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the my signals synchronization async u_txack with sync CLK:

```
if rising_edge(CLK) then 
            count<=count+B"00000001";                               
            n1_txack <= u_txack;
            if( n1_txack='0' AND u_txack='1')
                then
                u_txreq<='0';               
                count<=B"00000000";
            end if;             
            if (count=B"00000010") then
                u_txreq<='1'; 
            end if;                 
    end if;
```